# cant convert ascii charcters to int and hex at the same time

Tags: c++, hex

i have aproblem converting ascii charcters to int and hex at the same time

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{


    for (int i=0;i<265;i++){
        cout<<char(i)<<"               ";
        cout<<int(i)<<endl;
         cout << hex<< i<<endl ;
}
```

here is the result

```
                   0               0
               1               1
               2               2
               3               3
               4               4
               5               5
               6               6
               7               7
               8               8
                       9               9

               a               a
               b               b
               c               c
               d               d
               e               e
               f               f
               10               10
               11               11
               12               12
               13               13
               14               14
               15               15
               16               16
               17               17
               18               18
               19               19
               1a               1a
              1b               1b
               1c               1c
               1d               1d
               1e               1e
               1f               1f
                20               20
!               21               21
"               22               22
#               23               23
$               24               24
%               25               25
&               26               26
'               27               27
(               28               28
)               29               29
*               2a               2a
+               2b               2b
,               2c               2c
-               2d               2d
.               2e               2e
/               2f               2f
0               30               30
1               31               31
2               32               32
3               33               33
4               34               34
5               35               35
6               36               36
7               37               37
8               38               38
9               39               39
:               3a               3a
;               3b               3b
<               3c               3c
=               3d               3d
>               3e               3e
?               3f               3f
@               40               40
A               41               41
B               42               42
C               43               43
D               44               44
E               45               45
F               46               46
G               47               47
H               48               48
I               49               49
J               4a               4a
K               4b               4b
L               4c               4c
M               4d               4d
N               4e               4e
O               4f               4f
P               50               50
Q               51               51
R               52               52
S               53               53
T               54               54
U               55               55
V               56               56
W               57               57
X               58               58
Y               59               59
Z               5a               5a
[               5b               5b
\               5c               5c
]               5d               5d
^               5e               5e
_               5f               5f
`               60               60
a               61               61
b               62               62
c               63               63
d               64               64
e               65               65
f               66               66
g               67               67
h               68               68
i               69               69
j               6a               6a
k               6b               6b
l               6c               6c
m               6d               6d
n               6e               6e
o               6f               6f
p               70               70
q               71               71
r               72               72
s               73               73
t               74               74
u               75               75
v               76               76
w               77               77
x               78               78
y               79               79
z               7a               7a
{               7b               7b
|               7c               7c
}               7d               7d
~               7e               7e
               7f               7f
�               80               80
�               81               81
�               82               82
�               83               83
�               84               84
�               85               85
�               86               86
�               87               87
�               88               88
�               89               89
�               8a               8a
�               8b               8b
�               8c               8c
�               8d               8d
�               8e               8e
�               8f               8f
�               90               90
�               91               91
�               92               92
�               93               93
�               94               94
�               95               95
�               96               96
�               97               97
�               98               98
�               99               99
�               9a               9a
�               9b               9b
�               9c               9c
�               9d               9d
�               9e               9e
�               9f               9f
�               a0               a0
�               a1               a1
�               a2               a2
�               a3               a3
�               a4               a4
�               a5               a5
�               a6               a6
�               a7               a7
�               a8               a8
�               a9               a9
�               aa               aa
�               ab               ab
�               ac               ac
�               ad               ad
�               ae               ae
�               af               af
�               b0               b0
�               b1               b1
�               b2               b2
�               b3               b3
�               b4               b4
�               b5               b5
�               b6               b6
�               b7               b7
�               b8               b8
�               b9               b9
�               ba               ba
�               bb               bb
�               bc               bc
�               bd               bd
�               be               be
�               bf               bf
�               c0               c0
�               c1               c1
�               c2               c2
�               c3               c3
�               c4               c4
�               c5               c5
�               c6               c6
�               c7               c7
�               c8               c8
�               c9               c9
�               ca               ca
�               cb               cb
�               cc               cc
�               cd               cd
�               ce               ce
�               cf               cf
�               d0               d0
�               d1               d1
�               d2               d2
�               d3               d3
�               d4               d4
�               d5               d5
�               d6               d6
�               d7               d7
�               d8               d8
�               d9               d9
�               da               da
�               db               db
�               dc               dc
�               dd               dd
�               de               de
�               df               df
�               e0               e0
�               e1               e1
�               e2               e2
�               e3               e3
�               e4               e4
�               e5               e5
�               e6               e6
�               e7               e7
�               e8               e8
�               e9               e9
�               ea               ea
�               eb               eb
�               ec               ec
�               ed               ed
�               ee               ee
�               ef               ef
�               f0               f0
�               f1               f1
�               f2               f2
�               f3               f3
�               f4               f4
�               f5               f5
�               f6               f6
�               f7               f7
�               f8               f8
�               f9               f9
�               fa               fa
�               fb               fb
�               fc               fc
�               fd               fd
�               fe               fe
�               ff               ff
               100               100
               101               101
               102               102
               103               103
               104               104
               105               105
               106               106
               107               107
               108               108

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 10ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

but if i put them like in two different loops it work
and i get ascii and int
then 
ascii and hex
but i want them together not in a different loop
what i want is like this

ascii     int       hex

any help

Comment: How is `hex` defined?  That is, how does `cout << hex<< i<<endl` get compiled successfully?

Comment: @wallyk: It's a manipulator. Including `<iostream>` (among other possibilities) is enough to compile code that uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting for the base in which to print integers is "sticky", so it remains set until you change it. To mix decimal and hex like this, you'll need to explicitly set it before each item you print:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 265; i++) {
        cout << char(i) << "\t";
        cout << dec << i << "\t";
        cout << hex << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

Also note that `i` is already an `int`, so the cast to `int` was unnecessary.

Likewise I'd advise avoiding `std::endl` completely. "\n" suffices for the task at hand, and while you probably don't care about the difference in speed in this *particular* case, it is quite a bit faster as a rule (and in other cases, the speed difference really does matter).

You only need to include `<iomanip>` when you use a manipulator that takes an argument, like `std::setw(5)`, not the ones that don't take arguments like `std::hex` (strange rule, I know).

Comment: note im just student no a pro program but i will keep that in mind and start using /n